# How to return a different view with object in Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

In .NET Framework MVC, I could do it with the following codes:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Student student = new Student()
        {
             Id = 2, Name = "Mike"
        };

        return View("About", student);
    }
}
```

How do I convert the code above to Razor Pages (not MVC). At the moment for Razor Pages, I can only return the object to the same Page by making use the of the `[BindProperty]` attribute and the return is just basically `return Page()` and for redirect, I would just use `return RedirectToPage("/Home/About");`.

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Controller","About"). And create a new Action About to call view "About":that you want.

Comment: `RedirectToPage` is the correct method. You can use TempData (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tempdata) to pass the student to the About page when you redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out how already.

```
return new RedirectToPageResult("About", student);
```