# How to display FastReport in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, fastreport

Iam using Razor Pages web app .Net Core 6.
I have a report (FastReport) which i want to display on Page.

Here is the code:
`

```
using FastReport.Report report = new ();
        var reportPath = _env.WebRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo("Reports/ConsumerStatement.frx")?.PhysicalPath;
        report.Load(reportPath);
        report.RegisterData(data, "RefData");`
```

Everything is working fine. In .Net Core MVC reports is successfully displayed by:
`return View(report);

but I cannot figured out how to display this report in Razor Pages because return Page() is not accepting any parameter.

How can i display this report in razor page??

Comment: See this link for redirecting to a page with an object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759375/how-to-return-a-different-view-with-object-in-razor-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pass the value to razor view with ViewBag/ViewData as the [doc](https://www.fast-report.com/en/blog/show/use-WebReport-with-ASP-Net-Core/) of FastReport,ViewBag/ViewData is accessable both in RazorPage and MVC projects

in PageModel:

```
ViewBag.Report=report;
```

In RazorView:

```
@ViewBag.Report.......
```